# Entity Framework: Find all Cross Schema Queries in Code

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a way in Entity Framework Core to identity all Cross Schema Queries?

We have two SQL Schemas in our database, Finance and Customer. Our plan is to identify which are cross query SQL Queries, remove them, and migrate to a Microservice Architecture. Data will be shared with another Azure cloud tool.

Is there a tool In Visual Studio 2019 which displays this?

Using Net Core 3.1 with SQL Server 2019

Comment: As far as I know, there doesn't contain this tool in VS 2019. If you are [executing raw SQL queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql) using EF Core, you could try to check the SQL command, whether it contains different schema name, if it exists, it means this query is a Cross Schema Query.

Comment: Run profiler against your integration test

Comment: Rather elaborate, but you could use a command interceptor that logs each query in which both schemas occur. Getting 100% code coverage is another challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of such a tool. Your best bet is to manually evaluate all the table mapping you have on entities (do not forget your Dbcontext class), all queries. Make sure to cover Linq queries as well as raw SQL queries and stored procedures.

I have been through a couple of the monolith to micro service architecture efforts now. If you spend extra  time upfront getting things right you will be more successful in the long run.